# Media purchase and download website that doesn't use proprietary software

Tags: webapp-rec, video, music, download

The thing I hate about Itunes is that you have to use proprietary software.  What website can you buy the same (mostly) commercial music, and just download mp3's or whatever **through a web browser**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon [offers this](http://www.amazon.com/MP3-Music-Download/b/?node=163856011), but only for music. Also, as GAThrawn said, you can only download your purchase without proprietary software if it's a single track and not an album.

Comment: Amazon used a proprietary downloader app last time that I used it, though the whole of the rest of the buying experience and the file that comes out of the other end are all open for web browsers.

Comment: That's optional.

Comment: Really? Is that new? I looked around the first few times I used the service and I couldn't see any option to download MP3s without using their downloader.

Comment: @GAThrawn, there's a link at the bottom of the download page that you have to hit if you don't want to download the program, it's not real obvious, took me a minute to find it.

Comment: Ah, +1'd you both. The Amazon FAQ agrees with you, but only for single tracks, it says that for buying entire albums your only choice is using the downloader, or cancelling the purchase (on both .com and .co.uk anyway).

Comment: @GAThrawn, thanks for the details.

Comment: @GAThrawn: Thanks, i've edited that into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Emusic](http://emusic.com) is pretty good and cheap, too. The downside is that it does not have as large a selection as some of the others. Also, it is a subscription based model.

Comment: It appears that they have a Download Manager, so it seems like it'd be a proprietary interface, but they have a contact link for me to ask them if it's required.